# Pass variable From child to parent, Like a Function VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, vba, parent

I have created 2 forms (Parent & Child), i want to store the unique textbox value to a variable into the parent form.

Also like this:

Parent Code:

```
dim passed_value = new childform()
passed_value.show()
```

On close:

refresh passed_value variable using childform textbox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Do the Following to accomplish the Task :

- Declare a `String` variable in the child form.

```
    Public value As String
```

- Use `ShowDialog()` in the Main Form to show the Child form.

```
    Dim frm As New Form2
    frm.ShowDialog()
```

- [Set the `value` in your form as per your needs]

```
    value = "New Value"
```

- Now get the `value` variable from the Child form and set the textbox text according to it.

```
    TextBox1.Text = frm.value
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make it a property and give it the necessary access, which to me looks to be `ReadOnly`.

```
Private _myValue As DataType

Public ReadOnly Property MyValue() As DataType
Get
    Return _myValue
End Get
```

You could access it as such: `myForm.MyValue`.